# How to draw a number of images on an figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to see the effect of a continuous drawing, with the following code(in python3):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time as time

fg = plt.figure()
ax = fg.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.ion()
for d in range(3):
    x_data = np.array([])
    y_data = np.array([])
    #plt.clf()
    for t in range(v):
        x = t
        x_data = np.append(x_data,x)
        y = t*d
        y_data = np.append(y_data,y)
    #ax.lines = ax.plot(x_data,y_data)
    plt.plot(x_data,y_data)
    #plt.show()
    #plt.pause(0.3) 
    time.sleep(0.3)
plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

but it always doesn't work(it while draw 3 pic),Whether I put the code(plt.show()) in the loop or outside.

Comment: I'm sorry, I might not have described it clearly. My purpose wants to continue 3 charts on a graph, at intervals of 0.3s

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. Never use `time.sleep` in a GUI application. It will let the application sleep (=freeze)
2. If using `plt.ion()` one would call `plt.pause()` to introduce some delay.
3. Before calling `plt.show()`, turning interactive mode off via `plt.ioff()` makes sense, otherwise the plot will directly disappear after the loop.

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fg = plt.figure()
ax = fg.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.ion()
for d in range(3):
    x_data = np.array([])
    y_data = np.array([])
    v=3
    for t in range(v):
        x = t
        x_data = np.append(x_data,x)
        y = t*d
        y_data = np.append(y_data,y)

    plt.plot(x_data,y_data)

    plt.pause(0.3) 

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Instead of interactive mode, one may use `FuncAnimation`. The above would then look like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fg = plt.figure()
ax = fg.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def update(d):
    x_data = np.array([])
    y_data = np.array([])
    v=3
    for t in range(v):
        x = t
        x_data = np.append(x_data,x)
        y = t*d
        y_data = np.append(y_data,y)

    plt.plot(x_data,y_data)

ani = FuncAnimation(fg, update)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried your proposal, but it would draw three pictures.
How to show them in a picture, I'm trying to use (animation.FuncAnimation)

Comment: @user7733855 I just wanted to suggest to use FuncAnimation. That's defintely the way to go here. https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html

Comment: The code from the answer above runs fine and produces one single figure, which updates dynamically. If this is not the case for you, you probably run this in an environment, which does not support interactive mode. In that case, it also wouldn't help to use `FuncAnimation`. Instead you need to clearly state which environment that is.